# coldfusion + xml get nodes for a specified attribute

Tags: xml, coldfusion

Given the following XML:

```
<LiveScores>
    <Competition id="4915" name="Comp1" type="Union" group="">
        <Match id="1678" round="No Round" period="2" periodMinutes="40" matchTime="H2 40:06" previewArticleID="102948" matchReportArticleID="" status="Complete" alternateId="40790106">
            <MatchDate startDateLocal="2010-11-27 20:45:00" startDateUTC="2010-11-27 19:45:00" dayName="Sat" shortDate="27-Nov">2010-11-27 20:45:00</MatchDate>
        </Match>
        ...more matches
    </Competition>
    <Competition id="4916" name="Comp2" type="Union" group="">
        <Match id="1678" round="No Round" period="2" periodMinutes="40" matchTime="H2 40:06" previewArticleID="102948" matchReportArticleID="" status="Complete" alternateId="40790106">
            <MatchDate startDateLocal="2010-11-27 20:45:00" startDateUTC="2010-11-27 19:45:00" dayName="Sat" shortDate="27-Nov">2010-11-27 20:45:00</MatchDate>
        </Match>
        ...more matches
    </Competition>
    ...more competitions
</LiveScores>
```

Given a specified competition id (e.g. 4915), how do I return only the Competition node which has this id and no other competition nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the xml, and then run an [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) query using the [XmlSearch](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_24.html) function.

```
<!--- parse the xml --->
<cfset variables.livescoresXML = xmlParse(xml) />
<!--- run the query for the competition node wit id of 4915 --->
<cfset variables.myElements = XmlSearch(
    variables.livescoresXML,
    "/LiveScores/Competition[@id=4915]"
 ) />
```